# The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an issue when attempting to add a migration in EF.  The error is

> RegisterCountLog_Register_Target_RegisterCountLog_Register_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

The classes are as follows:

```
public class RegisterCountLog
{
    [ForeignKey("CountLog")]
    public long DeviceSerial { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("CountLog")]
    public long LogEntryID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    [ForeignKey("Register")]
    public long RegisterId { get; set; }

    public long Value { get; set; }

    public virtual CountLog CountLog { get; set; }

    public virtual Register Register { get; set; }
}

public class Register
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long RegisterId { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Device"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public long DeviceSerial { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RegisterName { get; set; }

    public ContributionType Contribution { get; set; }    

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegisterCountLog> CountLogs { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Hence register model has a composite key `RegisterId` and `DeviceSerial`, you have to specify both keys in `RegisterCountLog` model.

```
[ForeignKey("RegisterId,DeviceSerial")]
public virtual Register Register { get; set; }
```

Comment: What difference does that make?

Comment: When you define a FK you must have a way to retrieve the foreign table you are referencing. You cannot retrieve the Register table with only one key, since it has 2 PK (1 PK does not uniquely define the Register class). Therefore you must clearly state all the PK of the foreign table.